# Parse android SDK - filter query by pointer

Tags: android, parse-platform

Each user in my User class holds a pointer to another class (The user's home).
I want to get all the users that points to the current user's home (his roomates).
How can I do that? The following code returns an empty list:

```
currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseObject home = currentUser.getParseObject("home");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
query.whereEqualTo("home", home);
```

Notice: "home" is a pointer to the "Homes" class.

Answer (score 0):

Add **query.include("your_pointer_filed");** in your ParseQuery

Answer (score 0):

**Found an answer**:
Querying the User class is done in a special, different way than other classes.
Replaced:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
```

With:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```